# Find sum of all elements of an array excluding index L to R

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree

We have an array `arr[0 . . . n-1]`. We should be able to

1. Find the sum of elements from index L to R where 0 <= L <= R <= n-1 .
2. Change value of a specified element of the array `arr[i] = x` where 0 <= i <= n-1.

This can be solved using segment tree efficiently .

But how to solve opposite to this i.e.

1. Find the sum of all elements (arr[i]) from index 0 to n-1 excluding   L<= i <= R where L and R are given.
2. Change value of a specified element of the `array arr[i] = x` where 0 <= i <= n-1.

How to solve above question efficiently like segment tree?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: How is this different with the first question? just take "total sum **minus** sum from L to R"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can calculate sum(L,R) easily with segment tree.

First, calculate the total sum of whole array, called it `total`.

For a change in the `arr` at position ith

- Update the segment tree as usual.
- Update `total = total - oldValue + newValue`.

For each query , print `total - sum(L,R)`

Note: we can use [binary indexed tree](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees) (a.k.a [Fenwick tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree)) for this problem too, which IMO, is more suitable.